# Calculating Geometrically Linked Returns in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Calculating geometrically link returns

How do you multiply record2 * record1?

The desire is to return a value for actual rate and annulized rate

Given table unterval:

```
   EndDate    PctReturn
-------------------------------
1. 05/31/06   -0.2271835
2. 06/30/06   -0.1095986
3. 07/31/06    0.6984908
4. 08/31/06    1.4865360
5. 09/30/06    0.8938896
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
EndDate    PctReturn    Percentage   UnitReturn         
05/31/06   -0.2271835   -0.002272    0.997728               
06/30/06   -0.1095986   -0.001096    0.996634669                
07/31/06    0.6984908    0.006985    1.00359607             
08/31/06    1.4865360    0.014865    1.018514887                
09/30/06    0.8938896    0.008939    1.027619286


Percentage = PctReturn/100                          

UnitReturn  (1 + S1) x (1 + S2) x ... (1 + Sn) - 1
```

Aggregating values desired:

```
Actual Rate 2.761928596             
Annulized   6.757253223
```

Mathematics on aggregating value:

```
 Actual Rate    1.027619    1.027619-1  =   0.027619    * 100 = 2.761928596

 Annulized Rate 6.757253    (ActualRate^(12/number of intervals)-1)*100

 Number of intervals in Example = 5
```

there are only 5 records or intervals

I did try utilizing the sum in the select statement but this did not allow for multiplying record2 by record1 to link returns.  I thought utilizing the while function would allow for stepping record by record to multiply up the values of unitreturn.  My starter level in SQL has me looking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two option for getting a product in SQL Server.

**1. Simulate using logs and exponents:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7339e/8)

```
create table returns
(
  returnDate date,
  returnValue float
)

insert into returns values('05/31/06', -0.002271835)
insert into returns values('06/30/06', -0.001095986)
insert into returns values('07/31/06', 0.006984908)
insert into returns values('08/31/06', 0.014865360)
insert into returns values('09/30/06', 0.008938896)

select totalReturn = power
  (
    cast(10.0 as float)
    , sum(log10(returnValue + 1.0))
  ) - 1
from returns;

with tr as
(
  select totalReturn = power
  (
    cast(10.0 as float)
    , sum(log10(returnValue + 1.0))
  ) - 1
  , months = cast(count(1) as float)
  from returns
)
select annualized = power(totalReturn + 1, (1.0 / (months / 12.0))) - 1
from tr;
```

This leverages logs and exponents to simulate a product calculation. More info: [User defined functions](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/user-defined-functions/).

The one issue here is that it will fail for return < -100%. If you don't expect these it's fine, otherwise you'll need to set any values < 100% to -100%.

You can then use this actual return to get an annualized return as required.

**2. Define a custom aggregate with CLR:**

See [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

You can create a CLR custom function and then link this an aggregate for use in your queries. This is more work and you'll have to enable CLRs on your server, but once it's done once you can use it as much as required.

Comment: Thank you @Ian that works great. Since we are talking about investment portfolios, They maybe able to loose more that 100% as they can borrow funds.  I did notice that there is a function named lag and utilizing it with the over function. What do you think about the use of these functions verse you prescribed method?  Again thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. LAG and LEAD are SQL Server 2012, so won't be usable if you're on 2008. Even on 2012 they wouldn't help in this case, as you're still only able to used in conjunction with the standard aggregate and ranking functions, which don't include PRODUCT. Given you might have returns -100% maybe the CLR option would be worth investigating?

Comment: Also, if the answer is helpful don't forget to upvote and if it solves your issue please consider marking it as the accepted answer!