# SQL Stored Procedure - Calculate Geometric Linkage Returns

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table for an account monthly performance returns.  I need to create a stored procedure to calculate geometric linkage returns and store them on a new table.

Here is the 3 Months Return calculation from the latest date (i.e. 09/30/17):
     Answer={[(1+(1.18%)/100)*(1+(-0.12%)/100)*(1+(0.78%)/100)]-1}*100

The calculation for the Year To Date is the same except that it starts from 01/31/17 to 09/30/17.

The Since Inception starts from 07/31/16 to 09/30/17.

```
Date        Return
------------------
07/31/16    2.33%
08/31/16    2.08%
09/30/16    0.31%
10/31/16    0.15%
11/30/16    -0.30%
12/31/16    1.97%
01/31/17    0.89%
02/28/17    1.57%
03/31/17    -0.54%
04/30/17    1.06%
05/31/17    1.11%
06/30/17    0.01%
07/31/17    1.18%
08/31/17    -0.12%
09/30/17    0.78%
```

```
Results

Date        3 Months Return   Year To Date   Since Inception
------------------------------------------------------------
9/30/2017   1.85%             6.07%          13.16%
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Question is missing. You need to clarify what the question is.

Comment: How do I go about creating a stored procedure to calculate the 3 Months, Year To Date and Since Inception returns?  I have provided a sample calculation above if I do it in Excel.

Comment: After continue searching, I found a way to multiply values from the same column: exp(sum(log(value))).  I was able to create a procedure above to calculate the '3 Months Return', but I don't know how to simultanously calculate the 'Year To Date' and 'Since Inception'.  Please help.

Comment: BEGIN
    SELECT account_id,ROUND((exp(sum(log(1+return)))-1)*100,5) as     
    return, date_add(medate, INTERVAL 2 month) as Date FROM     
    returns x WHERE medate >= ALL(SELECT 
    date_add(medate, INTERVAL -2 month) FROM returns y 
    WHERE y.account_id = x.account_id)
    GROUP BY account_id;
END

Comment: Try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540724/calculating-geometrically-linked-returns-in-sql-server-2008